# Define variables u=using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am new to javascript, how can I write this using for loop?

```
SortingPageAudio.prototype.cardAudios = function(cardNumber) {
    var page = tabs.page;
    var card1Audio = page.card1Audio;
    var card2Audio = page.card2Audio;
    var FRcard1Audio = card1Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard2Audio = card2Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    if(cardNumber == '1')
    {
      playAudio.playFiles(FRcard1Audio));
    }
    else if(cardNumber == '2')
    {
      playAudio.playFiles(FRcard2Audio));
    }
};
```

Comment: You want a loop on what collection?

Comment: Write *what* using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any need for a loop, as the function either does card 1 or card 2. If you want the code to be less repetitive, you can do this:

```
SortingPageAudio.prototype.cardAudios = function(cardNumber) {
    var cardAudio = tabs.page["card" + cardNumber + "Audio"];
    var FRcardAudio = cardAudio.replace("e_", "f_");
    playAudio.playFiles(FRcardAudio);
};
```

In JavaScript, you can refer to a property either using dot notation and a property name literal (`obj.foo`), or using brackets notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression.

If you wanted to call `cardAudios` for both cards, you could do it like this:

```
[1, 2].forEach(instance.cardAudios, instance);
```

*(Where `instance` is a `SortingPageAudio` instance.)*

Or with a simple `for` loop:

```
var card;
for (card = 1; card <= 2; ++card) {
    instance.cardAudios(card);
}
```

Or of course:

```
instance.cardAudios(1);
instance.cardAudios(2);
```